# Firebase cloud functions realtime db parallel requests

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an issue with handling parallel requests with cloud functions. 
My scenario is to select a driver from the db and update its status. 
I do check for that status property before updating it, but when I send multiple requests (database on create triggers to be specific) within a second it doesn't seem to read the updated status property. 
 And it always updates with the information of the last request. 
 I also have noticed that sometimes the requests are processed altogether. 
What can I do to fix these issues?

**index.js**

```
const db = app.database();
const TripManagementUtil = require('./utils').TripManagementUtil;

exports.triggerNotifications = functions.database.ref('/Trip/{pushId}').onCreate( (snapshot, context)  => 
{
    var newTrip = snapshot.val();
    var tripKey = context.params.pushId;
    var tripManagementUtil = new TripManagementUtil();
    tripManagementUtil.searchDrivers(tripKey, newTrip, db);    
});
```

**utils.js**

```
searchDrivers(tripKey, trip, db){

    const results = [];
    var lat = trip.pickupLocation.lat, long = trip.pickupLocation.lng;
    var vehicleTypeID = trip.vehicleTypeID;
    var alreadyAssigned = trip.alreadyAssigned;
    var self = this;

    if(alreadyAssigned == null || alreadyAssigned == 'undefined'){
        alreadyAssigned = [];
    }

    const geofireQuery = new GeoFire(db.ref('vehicleLocation').child(vehicleTypeID + "")).query({
        center: [lat, long],
        radius: constants.searchRadius
    })
    .on('key_entered', (key, coords, distance) => {
        if(alreadyAssigned.indexOf(key) == -1){
            var result = {
                driverID: key,
                distance: distance
            }
            results.push(result);
        }  
    });
    setTimeout(() => {

        geofireQuery.cancel(); 

        if (results.length === 0) {
            self.noDriversHandler(alreadyAssigned, tripKey, db);
        } else {
            results.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);
            var driversAvailable = false;
            var index = 0;
            function checkDriver(){
                db.ref().child("driver").child("available").child(results[index].driverID).once('value').then(function(vehicleSnap){
                    var vehicle = vehicleSnap.val();
                    if(!driversAvailable){
                        if(vehicle != null && vehicle.vehicleTypeID == vehicleTypeID
                            && (vehicle.tripStatus != TripVehicleActionEnum.DriverConfirmed && vehicle.tripStatus != TripVehicleActionEnum.VehicleAssigned)
                            && alreadyAssigned.indexOf(vehicle.driverID +"") === -1){
                            driversAvailable = true;
                            self.driverExistsHandler(trip, tripKey, alreadyAssigned, vehicle, db);  
                        }
                        if(!driversAvailable && index + 1 == results.length){
                            self.noDriversHandler(alreadyAssigned, tripKey, db);
                        }  
                        index++;  
                    }
                    else{
                        index++;
                        checkDriver();
                    }
                });
            }
            checkDriver();
        }    
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: The code is still not showing how you update the database, but I assume you're looking to [save data transactionally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write data to the database where the value is based on an existing value, you'll want to use Firebase Realtime Database transactions. For more on this, and examples, see [save data transactionally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions) in the Firebase documentation.